# Main class could not be found or loaded

Tags: java

I have implemented a chat with RMI. The program runs as far as and in Eclipse it compiles without problems.
Only if I try to start the classes in the shell, I get the error
Main class (server.ChatProxyImpl) could not be found or loaded.
The programm has 3 projects: ChatClient, ChatServer and Interfaces.
I add the interfaces project into the buildpaths of the other projects.
I get the mistake. (ONLY via shell)

For test reasons I created a test class packed into the project ChatClient, which has a main and outputs a constant from the interfaces project. Works without problems, even on the shell.

So the error must be somewhere in the source code.

```
package server;
public class ChatProxyImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatServer, ChatProxy {
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(KONSTANTEN.PORT);
        Naming.rebind(KONSTANTEN.SERVERNAME, new ChatProxyImpl());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
```

Code got shortned.

Classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Interfaces"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Du musst die Frage auf Englisch posten bitte.

Answer (score 0):

When I run my java files in the terminal I need a .class file. I can get this by calling 'javac myJavaFile.java' in my terminal... remember first to find the directory of your java file and call your own .java file.

Then call 'java myJavaFile' and it should run :)

Comment: I know. I have .class files and navigated to the dic. dosnt run.

Comment: Did you try to make a new .java file?.. the biggest noob solution haha, but if you did´nt try, sometime these computers have the mind and 
behavior of its own :) hope you figure it out.